# Cordova how to get params from other app?

Tags: android, cordova

I used a share plugin to share contents to this app.
When I click the content from app, it calls my app and send params.
App starts as usual , but I don't know how to receive these params.
The params are an object like:

```
{module_id:'my module id',no:123}
```

Is there any way to receive these params ?

Something like:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onReady, false);
function onReady(params){
    // use params
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this [plugin](https://github.com/stample/cordova-sharingreceptor) to get shared text coming from other apps.

When your app gets started by other share-willing apps, you can simply call:

```
cordova.SharingReceptor.listen(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

to get all data that is sent to your app:

[image]

Within this Object (see picture above), the `data`- and/or `extras`-property should contain your params.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Let me know whether this answer helped you, please.

Comment: You are welcome. If this answer fulfills your request then mark it as right, please.